# Add backslash in HTML code with jQuery or JS

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace this code:
`<a href="test.html"></a>`

To this one:
`<a href=\"test.html\"></a>`

This is what I've tried so far:
`var source = $(this).val().replaceAll('"', '\"');`

Comment: You need to escape the escape.  `\"` is the same as `"` : `var source = $(this).val().replaceAll('"', '\\"');`    Example fiddle (but don't use fiddle console use browser console): https://jsfiddle.net/q6crgmLz/

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = $(this).val().replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

This will replace all instances of the double quote character with a backslash followed by a double quote.